# Is RPC a communication paradigm or an actual concrete protocol?

Tags: rpc

I'm struggling to understand what is exactly RPC (Remote procedure call), a way of thinking or an actual protocol ?

1. Is it a concept that promotes a layer of indirection for distributed communication or it is an actual protocol that ships with the OS (unix/windows) and it is used ONLY between some specific services ?
2. Can RPC be seen as an analogy to OSI model, where it answers to "WHAT" but not to "HOW", therefore it is used just for reference ?
3. To my understanding, **ANY (unidirectional, bidirectional)** communication between two processes (local/remote) seems to be what we call "RPC material". Is it correct ?

Thanks

Comment: This may be closed as requiring "opinion-based" answers.  My take: it's an activity.  A concept, yes, but not requiring indirection -- a RPC can be a low-level process - to - process communication without any layers of abstraction, or a high level API hiding the details.  Kind of like how the essence of REST is "using plain HTTP" if you strip away the purist use of 10 different request verbs (GET, PUT, DELETE, FOLD, SPINDLE, MUTILATE, ...)